# Cant connect to rds from ec2 , but can connect from my own computer

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have an rds and ec2 instance in tokyo region. 
I just set up an rds server to test stuff from my ec2 server.

When I type

> mysql -h remdev-experimental-BLEH-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P
>   3306 -uUSER -pPass

in ec2 the connection times out.

But i am able to get mysql access from my local computer. I  am able to perform operations just fine.

My rds is publicly accessible and my ec2 server allows all traffic into it , and from it

I tried restarting my ec2 server but that didnt fix this issue

Comment: Have you verified Security Group settings for RDS?

Comment: i can access it from my local computer ,and its publicly accessible

Comment: Doesn't matter. Security group rules may still be in play.

Comment: you were right! it seems it automatically added just my own ip address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to fix your RDS Security Group rules.